# How does my PC decide whether I meant a LAN or WAN adress?

Tags: networking, router, ip, lan, wan

I have understood how ip adresses and subnets work and that routers have two sides: LAN and WAN. Now I'm wondering what happens in the following scenario: I am 192.168.1.10 and my friend is 192.168.1.11 and the router is 192.168.1.1 (my default gateway, right?). Now I want to contact the global (WAN) ip adress 192.168.1.11 (let's say that adress was a big company which offers some kind of service). To my understanding my PC now says "wait a minute, that's my own subnet (255.255.255.0). I'll send that directly to the adress, not to the gateway". The gateway/router would have forwarded my data to the right destination, so how does my PC decide whether I meant the LAN or the WAN adress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this, because the 192.168 is a IP Range which is only meant for LAN addresses. It is the IP Range itself that makes us know we are inside a LAN, not a WAN.

In order to contact your friends LAN address, he has to setup a port forwarding rule in his router, and the router (which can be contacted by the WAN address) will then forward the connection to his pc.

So you connect to his WAN IP Address, which cannot be 192.168.x... 172.[16-31].x... 169.254.x.... or 10.x... Because these addresses are reserved for LAN addresses only.

So if your friend is in your network, then obviously it works, if your friend is not in the network, you need to use their WAN ip address. If you wanted to contact a big company, you would also contact them by their WAN ip address, which won't be any of the LAN ranges mentioned earlier.

If you were to actually setup your LAN to have overlap with public IP Addresses, then your router will broadcast the traffic to both your ISP and over the lan. Whoever responds first will get the reply which can yield in weird cases of random dropouts and slow speeds.

Comment: Okay so 192.* addresses are never given to routers on the WAN side, I get it. But on the LAN side of the router I can choose whatever I want right? So let's adjust my example to router LAN side = 172.217.0.1, me = 172.217.0.10, my friend = 172.217.0.11 and I try to contact 172.217.0.11 (global). Now I would probably get connected to my friend on the LAN instead of getting connected to the global address 172.217.0.11, right?

Comment: The example you gave 172.217.* is not included in the private IP space identified by IANA. You *can* choose to use it, but you'll likely run into issues eventually.

Are you asking if you assign a non-private IP to a LAN host, if when you try to connect to the IP in question, how does Windows know whether to connect to the LAN address or the (real) external address out on the internet? If so, I believe you'd be correct, your routing table would identify the LAN host as a valid destination for that IP and route traffic there instead of the internet

Comment: @Havegooda ah, good one. An oversight on my part.

Comment: yes havegooda, that's exactly what I was wondering after lpchip had enlightened me that what I originally had in mind is usually prevented by applied conventions. thank you both :)